# Undefinde symbol error when using python in PyCharm

Tags: python, qt, import, pycharm, anaconda

At my work PC (Scientific Linux 5), I have a Python2.6 installation at the usual /usr/bin path and a Anaconda installation with Python2.7 somewhere on some mounted network share /net/anaconda/...

`python`maps to the local python2.6 installation, `python27` maps to the anaconda one.

When opening `python27` in a terminal, everything works fine. When giving the interpreter path /net/anaconda... to PyCharm, everything works, except Qt. When doing `from PySide import QtCore` I get `net__software/anaconda/lib/libpyside-python2.7.so.1.2: undefined symbol: _ZN9QMetaType15registerTypedefEPKci`

I get the same when I `cd` into the path and run `./python` directly.

Is there any way to fix this on my own without going through the IT department? It would propably take some weeks until they get to such an minor issue...

Comment: But you say you run Python-2.6... The `.so` seems to be designed for Python-2.7.

Comment: No, I just have 2.6 as well. I'm trying to use the 2.7 version in PyCharm by giving PyCharm the path to the 2.7 interperter directly.

Comment: `net__software/anaconda/lib/libpyside-python2.7.so.1.2`... (with `-python2.7.so.1.2`...)

Comment: And as I said, when starting "python27" in the terminal, it all works fine. I just get the problem when I cd into /net/anaconda/python27/bin and run ./python directly from there - and in PyCharm, which basically does the same.

Comment: When you create a project in PyCharm, it makes you select which Python interpreter you want to use. It sounds like you selected the wrong one.